# Installing the RWD theme into Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I'm pretty new to Magento so have a feeling I'm making an extremely rookie mistake.

Basically, as a favour for my boss I'm trying to put a reskinned version of the basic RWD theme that comes with Magento onto our website.

I did the reskin, plucked it onto an old website I have for experimentation (http://www.hauntedcontraption.com.au/) and confirmed that it all works.

Copied the files across to their server (http://idsupplies.com.au/c50.com.au/) and no matter what I do, the menu seems broken.

I can see a strange ' ]> ' text output at the top of the c50 page, this output vanishes when I revert to the default theme on the site. I can't figure out where it's coming from as page.xml all appears intact and it's *exactly* the same file I'm using on the site that works...

I *do* note that my server (hauntedcontraption) uses Magento 1.9.2.3 and work's version of Magento are different (work is using 1.7.0.2).

Is there anything stupidly obvious you guys can see that I'm missing?
Is there enough of a difference between 1.9 and 1.7 that the menu in RWD theme won't work?

Comment: to clarify... the RWD theme in question is the plain blue & white one that comes with Magento 1.9.

All I've done is change the colours...

Comment: Do you want to upgrade your magento or just want to use RWD in 1.7?

Comment: I just want to use RWD in 1.7, there's a few extensions they use that apparently don't work in 1.8 or higher

Comment: Copy RWD theme from 1.9 and copy and paste package from `app/design/frontend` and `skin/frontend` folder and change theme from backend

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did...

Comment: any error  that you face??

Comment: The error is exactly as described above. I performed the re-skin of the RWD theme that comes with Magento 1.9, this can be seen on http://hauntedcontraption.com.au (it's an old site I had for something else I use that as a testing ground now) so confirmed it worked in 1.9 --- when I installed theme to idsupplies.com.au/c50.com.au the menu isn't working for some reason. I didn't realise during my testing that they were running 1.7... Was wondering if there is some kind of dependency within Magento 1.9 that isn't in 1.7?

Comment: you can use some menu extension which help you

Comment: Yeah, the links are all to CMS pages anyway so I think I might just rewrite a new menu in anyway. Was just hoping to use the existing one (way less work!!)

Comment: Can I write as a answer ?

Comment: I don't know if I'd count that as an answer.... It doesn't bring me any closer to finding out *why* it isn't working...